How to find the Second Space from the right in Google Sheets?
I am looking for a way to find the second space from the right in Google Sheets and keep the text upto that second space. In Excel, this can be achieved by using the command
=TEXTAFTER(A1, " ", -2)

How can I do the same for Google Sheets?

you can use find() inside find() to get the position of the second space, that along with mid() should do it.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.


You may try with:
=regexextract(A2,"[^ ]+ [^ ]+$")



Perfect. That did it. Thank you.
